# iPhone application fails to run on iPod because it is not compatible

Tags: iphone, app-store, ipod-touch

I submitted an iPhone application to the app store, but it is failed to run on iPod touch with the message that it is not compatible.I'm not using any Phone features on the application 
when I first I submitted the application to the store I was using some deprecated methods on the new SDK. so I made pre-processor directives for the conditional compilation like this:

```
#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED > __IPHONE_2_2
  // iPhone 3.0 code here
#else   
#endif
```

Can this be the reason for the non compatible issue. I would appreciate any help.

Thanks in advance,
Sarah

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conditionally compiling for different versions of the OS shouldn't affect what devices the app can run on.

Make sure that you have correctly set the `Deployment Target` setting in your build settings for your app. It should be set to the lowest version of the iPhone OS that you support.

Would you be able to list a brief summary of the main features you're using in your app?

Comment: yes I already set the Deployment Target to the lowest version of the iPhone OS. The main features of the applications are saving some records to sqlite DB. Backup them using web service. launch mail application and displaying video.  But it is mentioned on iTunes regarding the requirements that it is compatible with iPhone only. and requires iPhone OS 3. How apple determined those requirements?

Comment: When you submitted the app to Apple through iTunes Connect you should have been presented with the choice of which devices your app will run on. The choice would be something along the lines of iPhone, iPod Touch, iPhone and iPod Touch. Is it possible you didn't select the correct option? You should be able to edit the information for your app and change this option.